# Composition - Reference to another class in Python

Tags: python

In my example below in Python, object x 'has-an' object y.  I'd like to be able to invoke methods of x from y.
I'm able to achieve it using @staticmethod, however I'm discouraged to do that.

Is there any way(s) to reference the whole Object x from Object y?

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 5
        self.y = Y() #instance of Y created.

    def add2(self):
        self.count += 2

class Y(object):
    def modify(self):
        #from here, I wanna called add2 method of object(x)


x = X()
print x.count
>>> 5

x.y.modify()
print x.count
>>> # it will print 7 (x.count=7)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the object which has the instance of a Y object:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 5
        self.y = Y(self) #create a y passing in the current instance of x
    def add2(self):
        self.count += 2

class Y(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent #set the parent attribute to a reference to the X which has it
    def modify(self):
        self.parent.add2()
```

Example usage:

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x.y.modify()
>>> x.count
7
```

Comment: Wow. Simplicity. I never had thought of passing self to object. Thanks. It works.

Comment: is this good practice to pass instance of parent class around?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's possible for you to use class inheritance? For example:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 5

    def add2(self):
        self.count += 2

class Y(X):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Y, self).__init__()

    def modify(self):
        self.add2()


y = Y() # We now create an instance of Y which is a child class of 'super' class X
y.modify()
print(y.count) # 7
```

Comment: Yes. Inheritance is another great design pattern of achieving it.